# Dreamweaver Find and Replace with Wildcard

Tags: replace, find, wildcard, dreamweaver

I've read through several post on here and googled around but I can't find the solution I'm looking for.
I have a lot of pages with:

```
<meta content="User Name" name="author">
<meta content="user.name@domain.com" name="email">
```

What I need to do replace all instances of User Name and User.name with a different value.
The "problem" is that the 'User Name' instance can hold any value.

I hope this is clear and that someone can help and explain how to do this.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
<meta content=\"([^"]*)\" name="author">
```

This is regex that will find matches what ever content is.

Please let me know if this was helpful.